# Sync Adapter period sync not working - why?

Tags: android

I have tried for two days now without rest but my sync adapter will never trigger after requesting periodic sync. The sync interval am requesting is 30 seconds but the onperform is never called even after changing to NO-FILTER in the logcat configuration. Please look at the code below, please help out. I have been banging my head around this with no hope. Though the account is successfully creating under the android settings account, and can successfully manually sync by refreshing.

## The AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter class

```
public class ServiceSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    //TODO change this constant SYNC_INTERVAL to change the sync frequency
    public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL               = 30; //60 * 180;       // 60 seconds (1 minute) * 180 = 3 hours
    public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME               = SYNC_INTERVAL/2;
    private static final int MOVIE_NOTIFICATION_ID      = 3004;

    public ServiceSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.i(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onPerformSync");
        //TODO get some data from the internet, api calls, etc.
        //TODO save the data to database, sqlite, couchbase, etc
        //notifyDataDownloaded();
    }

    /**
     * Send the notification message to the status bar
     */
    /*private void notifyDataDownloaded() {
        Context context = getContext();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg)
                        .setContentTitle("Sync Adapter")
                        .setContentText("New Data Available!");

        // Opening the app when the user clicks on the notification.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MOVIE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build()); // MOVIE_NOTIFICATION_ID allows you to update the notification later on.
    }*/


    /**
     * Helper method to schedule the sync adapter periodic execution
     */
    public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
        Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
        String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
                    .syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime)
                    .setSyncAdapter(account, authority)
                    .setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
        }
        //ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to have the sync adapter sync immediately
     * @param context The context used to access the account service
     */
    public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
        Log.i(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "syncImmediately");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context), context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get the fake account to be used with SyncAdapter, or make a new one
     * if the fake account doesn't exist yet.  If we make a new account, we call the
     * onAccountCreated method so we can initialize things.
     *
     * @param context The context used to access the account service
     * @return a fake account.
     */
    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {

        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE); // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        Account newAccount = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type)); // Create the account type and default account

        // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
        if (accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) == null) {
            if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
                Log.e(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "getSyncAccount Failed to create new account.");
                return null;
            }
            onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
        }
        return newAccount;
    }

    private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
        Log.i(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onAccountCreated");

        //ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);
        //ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), 1);

        ServiceSyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);

        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);





        syncImmediately(context);
    }

    public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
        Log.d(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "initializeSyncAdapter");
        getSyncAccount(context);
    }
}
```

## And the Service class

```
public class ServiceSync extends Service {

    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
    private static ServiceSyncAdapter myServiceSyncAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onCreate ServiceSync");
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (myServiceSyncAdapter == null) {
                myServiceSyncAdapter = new ServiceSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onBind ServiceSync");
        return myServiceSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

## The authenticator service class

```
public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {

    private AccountAuthenticator mAuthenticator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
        // Create a new authenticator object
        mAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticator(this);
    }

    /*
     * When the system binds to this Service to make the RPC call
     * return the authenticator's IBinder.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(AppUtils.LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return mAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }

}
```

## The authenticator class

```
public class AccountAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    public AccountAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // No properties to edit.
    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r, String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // Because we're not actually adding an account to the device, just return null.
    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            String s,
            String s2,
            String[] strings,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    // Ignore attempts to confirm credentials
    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    // Getting an authentication token is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // Getting a label for the auth token is not supported
    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // Updating user credentials is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s, Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // Checking features for the account is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account, String[] strings) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

## Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.international.sonet.eac5">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>


    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <provider
            android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
            android:name="com.international.sonet.services.StubProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true" />


        <!-- SyncAdapter's dummy authentication service -->
        <service android:name="com.international.sonet.services.AuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <!-- The SyncAdapter service -->
        <service
            android:name="com.international.sonet.services.ServiceSync"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

## The authenticator xml file

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
```

## The sync adapter xml file

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/content_authority"
    android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true" />
```

I am initialising my adapter from the home activity oncreate() like this

```
ServiceSyncAdapter.initializeSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

The ProviderStub extends ContentProvider

Comment: My syncadapter is never synced after every 30 seconds